# Spring Boot: Enable HTTPS for embedded tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, ssl, spring-boot

Created keystore with following command:
`keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650`

Added following setting in the application.properties file:

```
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=######
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
#server port config
server.port=8080
server.http.port=8081
```

Wrote following code:

```
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };

        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(initiateHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }
```

Application starts fine without any error. And I can see the following message in the logs:
`s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (https) 8081 (http)`

But when I send a request `https://localhost:8081/hello`, response sent back from server and there is no activity on server logs. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: And why should it... 8081 is your secure port not 8080...

Comment: What does "it doesn't go anywhere" mean? Is there anything mapped to `/hello`? Could you share a complete example that shows the problem?

Comment: Hi! Is it possible that externalize the  https related settings? Any concerns on the password?  What is the good practice doing this?  Thanks! `server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=######
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat`

Answer (score 1):

The startup message of the embedded Tomcat clearly states that your ssl/tls connection is running on the port you specified with `server.port`:

```
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (https)
```

So you are just having a wrong port/protocol combination. https://localhost:8080 should work.

But normally your browser should complain with a message stating this. Just out of curiosity you could check what happens in your browser when you call https://www.google.com:80